# uniquerValues - view is required to query stats from layerView" and feature-layer-adapter:insufficient-data

Tags: count, arcgis, esri, unique-values

I'm trying to make use of [uniqueValues](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-renderers-smartMapping-statistics-uniqueValues.html) function from ESRI ArcGIS for JavaScript 4.10.

However, it's failing with this message:

> message: "view is required to query stats from layerView" name:
>   "feature-layer-adapter:insufficient-data"

I have a `FeatureLayer` with features and a field called `sStatus`. I also have a `Legend` setup that is working just fine with a `UniqueValueRenderer` based on this `sStatus` field.

This is my code:

```
uniqueValues({
    layer: layer,
    field: "sStatus"
}).then(function (response) {
    // prints each unique value and the count of features containing that value
    var infos = response.uniqueValueInfos;

    console.log('test');

    infos.forEach(function (info) {

        console.log("Wells : ", info.value, " # of Wells ", info.count);
    });
}).catch(errback);
```

Note: if I change the field name to something as "`status`" the error message in the Console changes:

> message: "Unknown fields: status. You can only use fields defined in
>   the layer schema" name: "unique-values:invalid-parameters"

This shows that my field `sStatus` is right but I don't get why it doesn't work out of the box.

Any ideas why this is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I posted the question I got the answer by re-reading the `uniqueValues` function [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-renderers-smartMapping-statistics-uniqueValues.html).

The message was clear in the first place: it was missing the view.

There's a `view` parameter for the `uniqueValues` function that was not part of the sample code...

> view View optional
>
> A SceneView or MapView instance is required when a valueExpression is
>   specified.

So what I had to do was this:

```
niqueValues({
    layer: layer,
    field: "sStatus",
    view: mapView
}).then(function (response) {
    // prints each unique value and the count of features containing that value
    var infos = response.uniqueValueInfos;

    console.log('test');

    infos.forEach(function (info) {

        console.log("Wells : ", info.value, " # of Wells ", info.count);
    });
}).catch(errback);
```